# Kernel crash trace is random and not always the same

Tags: memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel, stack-corruption

Crash traces different each time when crashing. This is part of testing device with continuous rebooting(~300 reboots) the device to verify stability of product.

As mentioned below crash log (added two cases only for ref), every time is changing crash pattern i.e. crash different functions.

```
Call trace not giving any data, suspecting memory corruption?
```

But I don't see crash when added **debug_guardpage_minorder=2** option in kernel command line args.

'''
case1:

```
CPU: 1 PID: 2027 Comm: dnsmasq Tainted: P           O    4.1.52 #0
Hardware name: Broadcom-v8A (DT)
task: ffffffc022bc2ac0 ti: ffffffc01fcec000 task.ti: ffffffc01fcec000
PC is at down_write+0xc/0x60
LR is at unlink_anon_vmas+0xb8/0x258
pc : [<ffffffc0005040cc>] lr : [<ffffffc0001324d0>] pstate: 20000145
sp : ffffffc01fcefc90
x29: 0000007fe3a300a0 x28: 0000000000000000 
x27: ffffffc0006acfc8 x26: ffffffc000939ddf 
x25: ffffffc01fd04f38 x24: dead000000000100 
x23: ffffffc01fd04fb0 x22: 00ffffc01fc0b860 
x21: ffffffc01fc98038 x20: ffffffc0227c6a40 
x19: 00ffffc01fc0b868 x18: 0000000000000013 
x17: 0000007f7c45c5a0 x16: ffffffc000094db8 
x15: 0000000000502ac0 x14: 0000000000000002 
x13: 0000000000008060 x12: ffffffc02422d640 
x11: ffffffc01fd04f90 x10: 0000000000000000 
x9 : ffffffc02409a330 x8 : 0000000000000000 
x7 : 0000007fa3d49000 x6 : ffffffc025bd91d0 
x5 : ffffffc025546750 x4 : 0000007f7c3ba000 
x3 : 0000000000000000 x2 : 0000007f7c3ba000 
x1 : ffffffff00000001 x0 : 00ffffc01fc0b868 


case 2:

CPU: 1 PID: 2590 Comm: sh Tainted: P           O    4.1.52 #0
Hardware name: Broadcom-v8A (DT)
task: ffffffc025c77540 ti: ffffffc025c84000 task.ti: ffffffc025c84000
PC is at vma_interval_tree_insert_after+0x24/0x88
LR is at copy_process.part.7+0xa64/0x1340
pc : [<ffffffc000123954>] lr : [<ffffffc000090c14>] pstate: 600001c5
sp : ffffffc025c87d60
x29: 0000007fda782770 x28: ffffffc02ad08640 
x27: ffffffc03bc3fae0 x26: 0000000001200011 
x25: 0000000000000000 x24: 0000000000000000 
x23: 0000000000000000 x22: ffffffc025c6b018 
x21: 0000007f8b7c6a40 x20: ffffffc03bc3fab8 
x19: ffffffc026e000c8 x18: ffffffc000938bc0 
x17: 0000007f8b5bb2b0 x16: ffffffc0000918d0 
x15: 0000000000000002 x14: ffffffc025c6b090 
x13: ffffffc025c6b090 x12: 000000000000014a 
x11: ffffffc026f03ac0 x10: 00ffffc026f1d1d0 
x9 : ffffffc026eaa5f1 x8 : ffffffc02beaba00 
x7 : 000000000000013b x6 : ffffffc025c6b078 
x5 : 00ffffc026f1d1d0 x4 : 000000000000014a 
x3 : 000000000000013a x2 : ffffffc03bc3fad8 
x1 : 00ffffc026f1d178 x0 : ffffffc026e000c8
```

'''

Comment: Random crashes are usually symptom of 1- hardware issue, 2- power supply issue. For the first: run memtest86++ for sometime and see if you have errors. Sometime some overheating (dust), etc. For the second: you may have too many appliances on the same line, or the supply is not stable, or ... -- Sorry, but with random crashes we cannot dig further (and so they are often the hardest problem to find, e.g. if it is the kernel that modify randomly the memory because of a bug [but 9 of 10 is cause 1 or 2)

Comment: But I don't see any crash when added debug_guardpage_minorder=2 option in kernel command line args.

Comment: This may exclude 2, but not 1. Do you have an old kernel which worked fine? Try it again for few time (this could reduce chances of #1, but as you see on memtest, patterns matter: you get memory error not consistently, and often on specific patterns (and sequence speed). So for me the debug_ flag doesn't exclude memory error. In fact it would be very strange that the bug is in the normal path, and correct behaviour with such flag (and such flag should modify just few places in kernel). If machine is new: hardware defects are much more common than one think (have a twin machine to test).

Comment: Crashes show the victim of a kernel bug, not the perpetrator.  It's quite possible that a bug somewhere else is writing to the wrong place.

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi : If crash is because of hardware then how can using debug_guardpage option avoids the crash?

Comment: @harikumarvemula: welcome on strange hardware failure world. Really: test it. Good debugging means that one must not assume anything. Why? Often memory fails on few location, if you add an option, frequent paths could be in a safer memory location. Or just timing: guard may delay some memory access (some programs, like GCC are known to trigger memory failure because of memory usage patterns. I experienced both, but for sure there are many other reasons. Else, why a seldom used option will prevent random bugs?